# How to run php-fpm as root in docker

Tags: php, docker

When i run php-fpm in docker ,the default account is www-data ,but i want run as root in docker.

I edit the config file ,user and user group to root,but the I don't know how to add -R .so the container can't run.

Comment: It's not a good security practice. Why do you need to run it as root at all?

Comment: I want my php app can manage some files that crate by root.such as,my aria2 is run by root,but my netClodu is run by www-data.

Comment: I think the more secure way is to start your aria2 with the user `www-data`. That way security issue with your PHP won't have the potential to compromise all files in your system.

Answer (score 9):

If you check the default PHP-FPM container command, you will see that it uses the following default one: `php-fpm`. You can easily override it to `php-fpm -R`.

For `docker-compose`, I'm using the following config:

```yaml
services:
  fpm:
    image: php:7.3-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./zzz-docker.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zzz-docker.conf # Mount FPM config that runs FPM as root
    command: php-fpm -R # Allow running FPM as root
```

The config file is pretty simple:

```
; Config to run PHP FPM as root (requires the -R flag to be passed to the entrypoint)
[www]
user = root
group = root
```

Instead of mounting custom config and changing the command, you may build a custom image adding this config file to your Dockerfile and it will look like the following:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

COPY ./zzz-docker.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zzz-docker.conf

CMD ["php-fpm", "-R"]
```

The `zzz-docker.conf` file in these examples is located in the root directory of the project.

Remember that you should aware of the security risks of running PHP-FPM as root. I'm using the above config for development purposes only.

Comment: Theoretically php-fpm running as root would mean only the container itself could be broken into.. which shouldn't be any more of a problem than www-data having access to the container.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can run bash as a root user:

First, find docker container id for php-fpm:

```
$ docker ps

p, 0.0.0.0:8008->80/tcp   webserver
e4689b3c1bc5        php:7.2-fpm                            "docker-php-entrypoi…"   2 months ago        Up 41 hours         9000/tcp
```

Then run the following command:

```
$ docker exec -u 0 -it e4689b3c1bc5 bash
```

Then you can run bash as a root user:

```
root@e4689b3c1bc5:/var/www#
```